# jQuery-UI .button() causing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is weird and totally unexpected. In my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/8qmyg/10/), the code does not work if I do,

```
$("#id").button().click(function(){  
    ...
});
```

It works if I do,

```
$("#id").click(function(){  
    ...
});
```

What am I missing? For reference, I had used [this](http://jqueryui.com/button/).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/8qmyg/10/)

Comment: did you applied ")" in the end?

Comment: Yes. Please see my fiddle.

Comment: I have placed alert in "$("#reset").button().click(function(){" in your code and this function has called on Reset button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you are trying to get the text of button you are using

```
$(this).html() // it's giving you the html of the button as <span class="ui-button-text">Start</span>
```

Use

```
$(this).text()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8qmyg/13/)

**UPDATE:**

Use

```
$(this).html("<span class='ui-button-text'>Resume</span>");
```

Insted of

```
$(this).html("Resume");
```

This should be changed for all other button text i.e. Start, Pause.

Comment: The button is then loosing the inner margin. How to fix that?

Comment: @RahulDesai Or better yet, use `$(this).button('option', 'label', 'The text inside my button');`